# Show Jasmine screenshots in Azure DevOps test results

Tags: jasmine, azure-devops, protractor, azure-pipelines

I'm testing my application with e2e testing with Protractor and Jasmine. The code is on Azure DevOps and automatically builds and runs the tests.
Azure is so great, that you can actually generate test results with graphics when your test results are in a JUnit, xUnit,.. format.

I installed the protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter because I want to be able to show screenshots when a test failed. Locally on my pc it works great. Every time the screenshots are generated and put in the right place. It generates .png files and one .html file. In the html there is a reference to the .png files.

[image: example of screenshots output]

Now here is the problem: the screenshots are bundled in html but azure cannot form html into test results.

How can I let jasmine convert it to a format Azure will read, or how can I insert the screenshots in Azure without Azure complaining he can't read it?
I was already able to show test results generated by a jasmine reporter that generated a .xml file, this was not a problem. But getting screenshots/html into Azure DevOps...

Even if I could just attach an attachment to the tests with screenshots, would already be great.

I've looked everywhere on the internet for two days into three possibilities:

1. Maybe there is a plugin that will take screenshots and in some way include this in an xml Azure will read. Unfortunately I only can find plugins that generate html.
2. I tried to find a way that I could get Azure to accept an attachment of some kind or accept html, but it seems it won't.
3. I searched for ways to convert html to xml but I only seem to find the other way around.

### General question:

How can I show screenshots on the test results of tfs. For example in the Attachments (as shown in picture).

[image: picture of where I want the screenshots to come]

Comment: Can you share your pipeline?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I don't understand. How will this help to solve my problem? What is it you want to see specifically that will help you to formulate an answer? I really just don't understand how it can help

Comment: To try reproduce the issue, to check exactly what you try to do.

Comment: I run the e2e test with an npm script that runs the protractor script (after I did a silent install of the program so it is up and running for the tests). The next step in the pipeline is publishing the results. Right now I choose JUnit as "Test result format"  and refer to **/e2e-results-junit*.xml and **/e2e-results-screenshots.html where the test results are. The xml is read correctly but he gives an error for the html file of course because he expects JUnit and not an html file.

Comment: The reporter must not only generate the screenshots but they must be linked in the test results file. Very few generators do this. The standard Visual Studio TRX format supports this.

Comment: @jessehouwing there is a jasmine trx reporter but it doesn't seem to generate screenshots. Do you know of any reporter that generates screenshots and test results in TRX format?

Comment: Nope. Support for attachments is very scant. I tend to add a custom Pipeline Artefact.

Comment: That is just sad. Can you give more info about the Pipeline Artefact you use?

Comment: Were you able resolve this? Can you provide details on the solution you used?

Comment: I was not able to resolve this...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jasmine-trx-reporter](https://github.com/papa-pep/jasmine-trx-reporter). Install the npm package and add the following code to your protractor config. Also, don't forget to publish your trx files using the *Publish Test Results* task in Azure DevOps.

```
const TrxReporter = require('jasmine-trx-reporter');

jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new TrxReporter({
  folder: 'e2ereport/trx/',
  takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: true,
}));
```